# Why do we have two different tags for Common Lisp at SO?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I have observed that Lisp questions about **Common Lisp** have two tags: [`clisp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clisp) and [`common-lisp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-lisp).

Currently `clisp` has 23 and `common lisp` has 259 questions.

Isn't it a good idea to merge them both? When I log into SO, I have to click on both to see the new questions about Common Lisp, although both are about the same dialect of Lisp.

I think having a single tag for Common Lisp is more organized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure they're the same thing.  [CLISP](http://clisp.cons.org/) is a particular implementation of Common Lisp.

Update: I've already looked through and found one question where someone was talking specifically about the CLISP implementation, so I don't think we can torpedo the tag.

Answer (score 0):

If by CLISP, people really mean Common List, I would suggest that first we merge the two, then we make clisp an alias of common-lisp just in case someone will create the same tag again. This may require addition work though but I think it will be a good feature.